# How do I spawn a document in its registered application in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C#/WPF app which presents to the user a list of filenames of various sorts. Some are images, some are videos, some may be word documents, PDF files, CAD files, or whatever.

Which files are in the list are entirely under the control of the user.

What I need to do is to allow the user to select one of the filenames, click the button, and to have that spawn the registered application for that type of file, loading the filename that was selected as it starts.

Any ideas as to where to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the files actually exist, [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/53ezey2s.aspx) will open the file in the associated application.

Answer (score 1):

```
// should test for file
Process nativeProcess = new Process();
nativeProcess.StartInfo.FileName = filePath;
try
{
    nativeProcess.Start();
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    // if user cancels on first screen will throw exception in some situations  
    Debug.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
}
```